# Is $ \pi_{(0,0)}(X^{-1}AX)$ a polynomial in some neighbourhood around $A$?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, polynomials

I had a conversation with someone who said that the following function from the space of $2\times 2$ real matrices to $\mathbb{R}$ is a polynomial:

$$ \pi_{(0,0)}(X^{-1}AX)$$

where $\pi_{(0,0)}$ returns the value in position $(0,0)$ and $A$ is the matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1  \\
    2 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}

If I spell out this multiplication (with the $Adj(X)/|X|$ for $X^{-1}$ and denoting $X$ as:

\begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 & x_2  \\
    x_3 & x_4 \\
\end{bmatrix}

then the $(0,0)$ term gets:

$$ \frac{-2x_1 x_2+x_3x_4-3x_2x_3}{x_1x_4-x_2x_3} $$

In a neighbourhood of $A$, we're still going to get the denominator with some variables. I'm not seeing why it might have even a neighbourhood around $A$ where this is a polynomial.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez What do you mean? This is supposed to hold for all $2 \times 2$ matrices $X$. Do you mean to use the formula for $X^{-1}$ and then see if it cancels out the denominator somehow?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ah, yes - sorry, I added $A$ to the question, so $X$ is the variable. Plus, I just opened the formula for a general $X$ for this $A$, and I still do not see how this might be a polynomial -- I have $x$'s (elements of $X$) in the denominator that do not cancel out. Would still be grateful for a verification that I'm not going mad (in particular, that I'm not missing something obvious here).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes - added the result to my question. That's fine then -- just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious and silly. Will close the question. Thanks!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Actually, might it be a polynomial in some restricted domain around $A$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Nice - I get how that would refute it being a polynomial, but how are you able to see so quickly that infinitely many of its derivatives at any point are nonzero?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Great, thanks so much! Glad I posted this question after all, this whole discussion was very helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: You might also notice that the function isn't even defined when $X$ is singular, and as you approach such $X$ the function typically blows up (one-sided limits of $+\infty$ or $-\infty$).  Polynomials don't do that.